# Export file automatic download not working in Django

Tags: python, django, export

I have trouble when exporting excel file through export button it does not appear download automatically, but when I inspect element then selecting network if I clicked export status it will download, but for me it will hassle to inspect element instead just click one button. I used Chrome I already tried set to automatic download but the result will the same, Is this the issue for the new version of the web browser or in my code?

[image]

> This is my code

```
@csrf_exempt
def export_status(request):
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        cursor.execute("""
            SELECT tev_incoming.id,tev_outgoing.dv_no AS dv_no, tev_incoming.code, tev_incoming.account_no, tev_incoming.id_no, tev_incoming.first_name, tev_incoming.middle_name,
                    tev_incoming.last_name, tev_incoming.date_travel, tev_incoming.division, tev_incoming.section, tev_incoming.status_id, au.first_name AS incoming_by,rb.first_name AS reviewed_by,
                    tev_incoming.original_amount, tev_incoming.final_amount, tev_incoming.incoming_in AS date_actual, tev_incoming.updated_at AS date_entry,
                    tev_incoming.incoming_out AS date_reviewed_forwarded, tev_bridge.purpose AS purposes
            FROM tev_incoming
            INNER JOIN (
                    SELECT MAX(id) AS max_id
                    FROM tev_incoming
                    GROUP BY code
            ) AS latest_ids
            ON tev_incoming.id = latest_ids.max_id
            LEFT JOIN tev_bridge
            ON tev_incoming.id = tev_bridge.tev_incoming_id
            LEFT JOIN tev_outgoing
            ON tev_bridge.tev_outgoing_id = tev_outgoing.id
            LEFT JOIN auth_user AS au
            ON au.id = tev_incoming.user_id
            LEFT JOIN auth_user AS rb
            ON rb.id = tev_incoming.reviewed_by
            ORDER BY tev_incoming.id DESC;
        """)
        rows = cursor.fetchall()

    response = HttpResponse(content_type='application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename={date}-TRIS-REPORT.xlsx'.format(
        date=datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d'),
    )

    workbook = Workbook()
    worksheet = workbook.active
    worksheet.title = 'REPORT'

    header_font = Font(name='Calibri', bold=True)
    centered_alignment = Alignment(horizontal='center')
    border_bottom = Border(
        bottom=Side(border_style='medium', color='FF000000'),
    )
    wrapped_alignment = Alignment(
        vertical='top',
        wrap_text=True
    )
    columns = [
        'DV NO',
        'CODE',
        'ACCOUNT NO',
        'ID NO',
        'FIRSTNAME',
        'MIDDLENAME',
        'LASTNAME',
        'DATE TRAVEL',
        'DIVISION',
        'SECTION',
        'STATUS ID',
        'INCOMING BY',
        'REVIEWED BY',
        'ORIGINAL AMOUNT',
        'FINAL_AMOUNT',
        'DATE ACTUAL RECEIVED',
        'DATE ENTRY',
        'DATE REVIEWED FORWARDED',
        'PURPOSE',
    ]
    row_num = 1
    for col_num, column_title in enumerate(columns, 1):
        cell = worksheet.cell(row=row_num, column=col_num)
        cell.value = column_title
        cell.font = header_font
        column_letter = get_column_letter(col_num)
        column_dimensions = worksheet.column_dimensions[column_letter]

    for tris in rows:
        row_num += 1
        row = [
            tris[1],  # dv_no
            tris[2],  # code
            tris[3],  # account_no
            tris[4],  # id_no
            tris[5],  # first_name
            tris[6],  # middle_name
            tris[7],  # last_name
            tris[8],  # date_travel
            tris[9],  # division
            tris[10],  # section
            tris[11],  # status_id
            tris[12],  # incoming_by
            tris[13],  # reviewed_by
            tris[14],  # original_amount
            tris[15],  # final_amount
            tris[16],
            tris[17],
            tris[18],  # date_reviewed_forwarded
            tris[19],  # purposes
        ]       
        for col_num, cell_value in enumerate(row, 1):
            cell = worksheet.cell(row=row_num, column=col_num)
            cell.value = cell_value
            column_letter = get_column_letter(col_num)
            column_dimensions = worksheet.column_dimensions[column_letter]
            column_dimensions.width = 19
    workbook.save(response)
    return response
```

> my ajax

```
    $.ajax({
       type: 'POST',
       url: "{% url 'export-status' %}"
    }).done(function (data) {
                 
    });
```

Comment: Notice in your network pane the type of your request is XHR, that means your request was initiated by JavaScript. The browser won't save that automatically, you'll have to handle that (See duplicate).

Comment: @Abdul Aziz Barkat how should I fix this? what can you suggest?

Comment: ok thanks I just added "window.location.href = "{% url 'export-status' %}";" to my ajax